# How to fix this sorting?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

Use a Knuth-optimized quicksort where the quicksort operates on all partitions > k elements. The array is  partially sorted in this way, and then a single insertion sort is called to polish the results.

Use pivot = x[random element]

Given an input file "abc.txt" with the following format, read in data and sort it using the sort described above.  The first number is the number of elements to sort.

The input "abc.txt" is:

```
11

8 1 11 2 10 9 3 4 7 6 5
```

The output should be a row of numbers with ascending order.

Here is my code, but it does not work. Anyone can give me a help:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

void Qsort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    if(low >= high)
    {
        return;
    }
    int first = low;
    int last = high;
    int key = a[(rand() % (last - first + 1)) + first];

    while(first < last)
    {
        while(first < last && a[last] >= key)
        {
            --last;
        }

        a[first] = a[last];

        while(first < last && a[first] <= key)
        {
            ++first;
        }

        a[last] = a[first];    

    }
    a[first] = key;
    Qsort(a, low, first-1);
    Qsort(a, first+1, high);
}
int main()
{
    std::fstream myfile("C:\\abc.txt", std::ios_base::in);
    int y = 0;

    myfile >> y;
    int a[100000] = {}; 

    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        myfile >> a[i];
    }

    Qsort(a, 0, y-1); 
    for(int i = 0; i < y ; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::sort` is pretty good. Generally better than a DIY solution, and certainly less work. Anyway I think the question belongs on the code review site, not here, because it's nothing to do with the language and all to do with implementation of an algorithm.

Comment: I suggest the following improvements on the question (regardless of whether it's moved): (1) do elaborate on the "does not work", provide example input, expected output, actual output; (2) for the first part, state that it's the assignment text and make it a block quote, there's a button for it but essentially a `>` at the start of each line; (3) remove the out-commented code since it doesn't contribute, it's just noise.

Comment: Your question amounts to "my code does not work", which is wildly insufficient. Also I don't think you're _really_ Angelababy, though she is very cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you are giving `myfile` an incorrect path. I tested the code myself, and it worked as I would have expected. If I did not have an `abc.txt` at the correct location, the program would run and have no output. I assume this is what you are experiencing, although "does not work" is a tad vague.

If you do have an `abc.txt` in `C:`, my next guess is your read request is getting shot down by the OS for not having the correct permissions to access files there. Try putting the file in your documents folder.

Also, `rand` is located in `<cstdlib>`, not `<random>`. While it certainly seems that `<random>` would include `<cstdlib>`, I wouldn't rely on that. You'll also want to seed it with `srand`, or (as a better alternative) look into how to use `<random>`. It's more complicated at first, but is much better.

Comment: The path is where your file is located. Assuming the OS you have functions at all like Windows, opening the properties of "abc.txt" and copying the full path should fix it. Just replace every "\" with "\\" and use that path instead of the one in your program now.